# How to mask text in phonetextbox in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

In windows phone 8, if i selected phone text box and entered some text into it, i want to mask this text, how to achieve this ?

Comment: Like a password entry box then?

Comment: Do you mean you want to format your input? like phone number should have only numerics and may be formatted in this: 123-456-7890 format?

Comment: @PaulAnnetts: in asp.net we can mask our textbox by using textbox.mask, like that...!!!

Comment: @sunil5715: no, i don't want to format, i want to mask it.i am not talking about any validations.

Comment: Simple solution would be                                '<PasswordBox x:Name="txtPhoneNumber"
         ToolTip="Phone number"
         PasswordChar="*"
    />'                                                               Or see the another approach here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/824e5dda-c786-4f9a-af09-c64599a313fd/                         Hope this helps. if do then please mark this as answer.

Comment: @sunil5715: The 'tooltip', is usable like toolTipService.toolTip. By using the same also i'm not able to view any hint in the password box.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve my problem with this code :

in xaml :

```
<toolkit:PhoneTextBox Margin="-20,48,0,0"                              
                            InputScope="TelephoneAreaCode"
                            Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxStyleGreen}"                                              
                            x:Name="PhoneNumber" Height="72" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" MaxLength="10" Hint="Ceular"/>
```

viewmodel :

```
private string _phoneNumber;
    public string PhoneNumber
            {
                get
                {                
                    return FormattedPhoneNumber(_phoneNumber);                
                }
                set
                {               
                    _phoneNumber = value;                       
                    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => PhoneNumber);                
                }
            }

public string FormattedPhoneNumber(string pn)
        {
            if (pn == null)
                return string.Empty;

            switch (pn.Length)
            {
                case 5:
                    {
                        if (!pn.Contains("-"))
                        {
                            return Regex.Replace(pn, @"(\d{4})(\d{1})", "$1-$2");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return pn.Replace("-", String.Empty);
                        }

                    }
                case 9:
                    {
                        var sbPhoneNumber = pn.Replace("-",String.Empty);
                        return Regex.Replace(sbPhoneNumber, @"(\d{4})(\d{4})", "$1-$2");
                    }
                case 10:
                    {
                        var sbPhoneNumber = pn.Replace("-", String.Empty);
                        return Regex.Replace(sbPhoneNumber, @"(\d{5})(\d{4})", "$1-$2");                        
                    }                
                default:
                    {                        
                        return pn;
                    }
            }            
        }
```

my mask : if 8 numbers : 8888-8888 
          if 9 number  : 00000-0000

Answer (score 0):

**In your .XAML File add TextChanged event on your TextBox**

```
<TextBox Name="tvCelular" TextChanged="OnTextCelularChanged" MaxLength="14" InputScope="Number"/>
```

**Create a class Mask.cs**

```
/// <summary>
/// created by MAYCON CARDOSO
/// </summary>
public class Mask {
    private bool isUpdating = false;
    private string old = "";

    public String unmask(String s) {
        return s.Replace(".", "").Replace("-", "")
                .Replace("/", "").Replace("(", "")
                .Replace(")", "");
    }

    public void performFilter(string mask, TextBox ediTxt) {
        string s = ediTxt.Text;

        String str = unmask(s);

        String mascara = "";
        if (isUpdating) {
            old = str;
            isUpdating = false;
            return;
        }
        int i = 0;
        foreach(char m in mask.ToCharArray()) {
            if (m != '#' && str.Length != old.Length) {
                mascara += m;
                continue;
            }
            try {
                mascara += str[i];
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }

        isUpdating = true;
        ediTxt.Text  = mascara;
        ediTxt.SelectionStart  = mascara.Length;
    }
}
```

**In your cs file add this code**

```
 private void OnTextCelularChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {
        mCelularMask.performFilter("(##)####-#####",tvCelular);    
    }
```